# Only show rows in a table if something changed in previous row

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with a lot of records (6+ million) but most of the rows per ID are all the same.

Example:

| Row | Date | ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | a | b | c | d | e |
| 2 | 02-01-2021 | 1 | a | b | c | d | **x** |
| 3 | 03-01-2021 | 1 | a | b | c | d | **x** |
| 4 | 04-01-2021 | 1 | a | b | c | d | **x** |
| 5 | 01-01-2021 | 2 | a | b | c | d | e |
| 6 | 02-01-2021 | 2 | a | b | **x** | d | e |
| 7 | 03-01-2021 | 2 | a | b | **x** | d | e |
| 8 | 01-01-2021 | 3 | a | b | c | d | e |
| 9 | 02-01-2021 | 3 | a | b | c | d | e |
| 10 | 03-01-2021 | 3 | a | b | c | d | e |

To save space but also make querying easier I want to create a table where only rows are shown if there was a change vs the previous row (except for the date).

For above table this means I would only like to see:

- Row 1 > First entry for ID 1
- Row 2 > Because something changed vs the previous row
- Row 5 > First entry for ID 2
- Row 6 > Because something changed vs the previous row
- Row 8 > First entry for ID 3 and no changes after this

So the table would look like this:

| Row | Date | ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2021 | 1 | a | b | c | d | e |
| 2 | 02-01-2021 | 1 | a | b | c | d | **x** |
| 5 | 01-01-2021 | 2 | a | b | c | d | e |
| 6 | 02-01-2021 | 2 | a | b | **x** | d | e |
| 8 | 01-01-2021 | 3 | a | b | c | d | e |

I am trying to do this in PySpark and have had some success with 1 column only using `LAG` but having some trouble when there are more columns (there are about 20 in my own table). I would prefer to do this in PySpark but a working version in SQL or Python could also work!

I was wondering if there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a lagged array column of all columns of interest and compare it to the current row, then do a filter:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

cols = df.columns[3:]
w = Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('Date')

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'diff', 
    F.coalesce(
        F.lag(F.array(*cols)).over(w) != F.array(*cols), 
        F.lit(True)    # take care of first row where the lag is null
    )
).filter('diff').drop('diff')

df2.show()
+---+----------+---+----+----+----+----+----+
|Row|      Date| ID|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|
+---+----------+---+----+----+----+----+----+
|  1|01-01-2021|  1|   a|   b|   c|   d|   e|
|  2|02-01-2021|  1|   a|   b|   c|   d|   x|
|  5|01-01-2021|  2|   a|   b|   c|   d|   e|
|  6|02-01-2021|  2|   a|   b|   x|   d|   e|
|  8|01-01-2021|  3|   a|   b|   c|   d|   e|
+---+----------+---+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

if there is the column "Row" in your table you can do it fast in SQL:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM MyTable t1
INNER JOIN MyTable t2 ON t1.Row=t2.Row-1
WHERE t1.ID<>t2.ID OR t1.Col1<>t2.Col1 OR t1.Col2<>t2.Col2 OR t1.Col3<>t2.Col3 OR t1.Col4<>t2.Col4 OR t1.Col5<>t2.Col5
```

Comment: thank you for helping with SQL! I like your solution, simple but it works. For bigger tables the code gets very long though.